# Find all the natural numbers N such that the reduced residue system consisting of least positive residues modulo N form an arithmetic progression.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, reduced-residue-system

Firstly, I suppose that N is odd, then obviously the $1st$ term of the AP is $1$ and the $2nd$ term is $2$. Thus difference between $1st$ and $2nd$ term is $1$, thus the AP formed is $1, 2, 3, ... , N-1$. Thus $N$ must be prime. So we get that if $N$ is odd, then the R.R.S of $N$ forms an AP iff $N$ is prime. Now, suppose $N$ is even and not divisible by $3$, then $1st$ term is again $1$, $2nd$ term will be $3$. Here the common difference is $2$. Thus the AP formed is $1, 3, 5, ... , N-1$. This shows that $N$  must be a power of $2$. But, what if $N$ is even and divisible by $3$, or is there any better way to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a_1, a_2,...., a_n$  be the reduced residue system modulo N in increasing order . All.primes and powers of 2 work so we assume N is non or those.then $a_n=N-1$ and $a_1=1$ , then common difference is $\frac{N-2}{n-1}=d$ . If N is even  , then clearly so $(N, d)|(N, N-2)=2$ But that would imply there exists $x \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $dx+1$[our terms in progression] ,such that if N even has a single odd factor then $dx+1$ is divisible by that factor[as d and that odd factor are coprime] making a contradiction, so N should be power of 2 .

if N is odd, then $a_2=2$  , hence all positive integers less than n are corpime to n, not possible as then N is a prime

Comment: But that would imply there exists x∈Z
 such that dx+1
[our terms in progression] , such that if N even has a single odd factor then dx+1
 is divisible by that factor[as d and that odd factor are coprime]. What do you mean by this?

Comment: Say N=2^x * y where y is odd and y>1 , now consider the sequence dx+1 [this also becomes a1, a2,...,an] where 0<=x<=n-1 , now as (N, d)|2 , so (y, N)=1 as (y, N)=2 is not possible. this means there should exist integer x such that 0<=x<=y-1 such that (dx+1) is divisible by y as x>=1 , y<N, so 0<=x<=N-1 that would imply dx+1 and N are not coprime contradiction